# Angular 2 - Trocar o separador dos valores de virgula para ponto

Tags: angular, ionic2

Quero que o valor do meu Form retorne 2 número decimais e com vírgula separando ao invés de ponto.

> Ex: 20 -> 20,00

E caso o valor seja maior de mil ele tenha ponto separando.

> Ex: 1000 -> 1.000,00

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: através de diretivas https://github.com/castrolol/ng2-mask-money